# US based flights bicycle question

Tags: airport-security, american-airlines

Are rechargeable USB bicycle lights allowed on a flight within the United States? Also is a small round helmet mirror allowed on a flight? I will be flying American Airlines and want to know.

Answer (score 1):

There are no restrictions on those items in either checked or carry on baggage.  The only exception I can think of would be if your bike light has one of those older waterbottle sized rechargeable batteries (which aren't very common anymore).

Comment: Most airlines and airports follow the [FAA hazmat guidelines](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/hazmat_safety/) or a derivative version. If any attachment to the bike contains a LiPo or Li-Ion battery it should be removed from the bike before checking it in for the hold, and packaged separately in a protective container. If the battery is removable from the device it should be removed and packaged separately. While 95% of the time nobody will check or care, it's worth doing right for the 5% where someone gets uppity about it and you might end up losing the offending device.

Comment: @Polynomial -  a usb light would be easily removable and would naturally be packed independently from the bike otherwise it would likely be lost or damagwd in transit.  But if you feel your comment warrants down voting my answer so be it.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. I don't know why someone would. It was a good answer that I just felt like adding some additional context to.

Comment: Thanks the lights in question are a cateye 300 headlight and two bontrager flare rr rear lights the batterry is not removeable in either of the devices.

Comment: Whats a protective container will a ziplock bag work so i can just put the lights in my pocket or is there some approved protective container i need

Comment: Something that low power does not need a protective container, I would just put them in a ziplock bag so they are easily inspected by security if they wish to.